# Is there an easy way to sum $\sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation-method

I'd like to have a standard procedure to sum terms like $$\sum_{1\,\leq\, i\, <\, j\, <\, k\, \leq\, n} 1$$ without having to "telescope" the sum, beggining from the outermost one and simply summing up each partial sum obtained. More generally, how do I perform sums like $$\sum_{1\, \leq\, i_{1}\, <\, i_{2}\, <\, \cdots\, <\, i_{k}\, \leq\, n} 1?$$ I teach this stuff in a basic combinatorics class and it got pretty messy last time. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: $\binom n3$. Every triple of distinct numbers in the range shows up exactly once.  The generalization is straight forward.

Comment: You can prove it by induction, observing that $1 = \binom{n}{0}$ and using Pascal's formula

Comment: As a general comment:  Always work these things out for a number of small $n$. Often that makes the pattern clear, and in any case, it gives you a bunch of examples to compare to whatever formula you eventually find.

Comment: Hi, all. Thanks for the input! Yes, I know that the sum adds up to ${n \choose q}$, but I'm not finding an easy "algebraic" way out of the expressions without "handwaving" (however correct) arguments. (BTW: "Every triple of distinct numbers in the range shows up exactly once" is a good argument, indeed.) I was wondering if some kind of expansion $(a+b+\cdots+q)^n$ could help, like with generating functions. Anyway, thanks a lot for the input, I'll try to figure this thing out.

Comment: So-called [Iverson brackets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) might be helpful. You can write the last summation as repeated sum: $$\sum_{i_1=1}^n\cdots\sum_{i_k=1}^n[i_1<\cdots<i_k]$$where $[i_1<\cdots<i_k]$ takes value $1$ if indeed $i_1<\cdots<i_k$ and takes value $0$ otherwise. Taking that summation is (again) not more than a way to count the triples $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ that satisfy $1\leq i_1<\dots<i_k\leq n$. It is actually the same as counting subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ that contain exactly $k$ elements. Result: $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: You can do this: define $A_n(m)=\sum_{k=1}^m A_{n-1}(k), A_0(m)=1$. From the definition we have that $A_n(m)=\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^k A_{n-2}(i) = \sum_{1\leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq i_3 \leq \dots \leq i_n \leq m} 1$. We would need to modify some things of the index of the sums, since it is $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \dots < i_n \leq m$.

Comment: From the definition, we can conjecture that $A_n(m)=\frac{(m+n-1)!}{n!(m-1)!}={ {m+n-1} \choose n }$, and so, $A_{n+1}(m)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} { {m+n} \choose n }$